# .net Core 3.0, DirectoryNotFoundException with Xunit Integration test

Tags: c#, .net-core, xunit

I have a new issue working on migrating my Xunit integration test on .net core 3.0. I moved the project in a subfolder and now I have a DirectoryNotFoundException.

TestServerFixture:

```
public class TestServerFixture : WebApplicationFactory<TestStartup>
{
    public HttpClient Client { get; }
    public ITestOutputHelper Output { get; set; }

    protected override IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder()
    {
        var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.AddXunit(Output);
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder
                    .UseStartup<TestStartup>()
                    .ConfigureTestServices((services) =>
                    {
                        services
                            .AddControllers()
                            .AddApplicationPart(typeof(Startup).Assembly);
                    });
            });

        return builder;
    }

    public TestServerFixture SetOutPut(ITestOutputHelper output)
    {
        Output = output;
        return this;
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        base.Dispose(disposing);
        Output = null;
    }
}
```

Error message:

> Message: 
>       System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException : **C:\Users\Me\source\repos\tests\TestingWithDotNetCore3_0\MyIntegrationTests**
>   Stack Trace: 
>       PhysicalFileProvider.ctor(String root, ExclusionFilters filters)
>       PhysicalFileProvider.ctor(String root)
>       HostBuilder.CreateHostingEnvironment()
>       HostBuilder.Build()
>       WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder)
>       WebApplicationFactory`1.EnsureServer()
>       WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateDefaultClient(DelegatingHandler[] handlers)
>       WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateDefaultClient(Uri baseAddress, DelegatingHandler[] handlers)
>       WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateClient(WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions
>   options)
>       WebApplicationFactory`1.CreateClient()
>       WeatherForecastController_Tests.ctor(TestServerFixture testServerFixture, ITestOutputHelper output) line 25

The project is not in:

*C:\Users\Me\source\repos\tests\TestingWithDotNetCore3_0\MyIntegrationTests*

In TestServerFixture.CreateHostBuilder, the value returned by *Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()* is

*"C:\Users\Me\source\repos\tests\TestingWithDotNetCore3_0\src\tests\AllInOne.Integration.Tests\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.0"*

I tried:

```
    protected override IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder()
    {
        var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            **.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())**
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.AddXunit(Output);
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder
                    .UseStartup<TestStartup>()
                    **.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())**
                    .ConfigureTestServices((services) =>
                    {
                        services
                            .AddControllers()
                            .AddApplicationPart(typeof(Startup).Assembly);
                    });
            });

        return builder;
    }
```

But It doesnt work.

I did a repo to show you the issue:
https://github.com/ranouf/TestingWithDotNetCore3_0

Do you have any suggestion to configure it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution available here: I found a solution/hack which works for me, available here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57476187/6123422

In my case, the solution should be:

```
public class TestServerFixture : WebApplicationFactory<Startup>
{
    protected override IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder()
    {
        var builder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
            {
                logging.ClearProviders();
                logging.AddXunit(Output);
            })
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder
                    .ConfigureTestServices((services) =>
                    {
                        services
                            .AddControllers()
                            .AddApplicationPart(typeof(Startup).Assembly);
                    });
            });

        return builder;
    }

    protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.UseStartup<TestStartup>();    
        base.ConfigureWebHost(builder);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

I solved this by adding the following my fixture. It won't work if you add `UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())` in `CreateHostBuilder()`. Lost one-hour chasing ghosts. Ridiculous.

```
    protected override IHost CreateHost(IHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());    
        return base.CreateHost(builder);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the assembly name fixed it for me